# No me funciona Consulta Jquery ASPRESET API

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo una página que hace una consulta con jquery a una API RESET. Es tan simple cómo devolver unos pocos registros. Pero me sale undefined.

El código es el siguiente:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Trading Algorítmico -- Señales</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Señales -- > Trading Algorítmico
        </div>   <!--en dof panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="Table">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Hora</th>
                    <th>Instrumento</th>
                    <th>Señal</th>
                    <th>Volumen</th>
                    <th>Nivel</th>
                    <th>Dirección</th>
                    <th>Nivel</th>
                    <th>Funciono</th>
                </tr>   <!--end of table-row -->
            </table>   <!--end of table -->
        </div> <!--end of Panel-body -->
    </div> <!--end of Panel -->


    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/api/Signals",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                        $("#DIV").html('');
                        var DIV = '';
                        $.each(data, function (ID, item) {
                            var rows = "<tr>" +
                                "<td id='ID'>" + item.ID + "</td>" +
                                "<td id='Fecha'>" + item.Fecha + "</td>" +
                                "<td id='Hora'>" + item.Hora + "</td>" +
                                "<td id='Instrumento'>" + item.Instrumento + "</td>" +
                                "<td id='Señal'>" + item.TipoSignals + "</td>" +
                                "<td id='Volumen'>" + item.Volumen + "</td>" +
                                "<td id='Nivel'>" + item.Nivel + "</td>" +
                                "<td id='Dirección'>" + item.Direccion + "</td>" +
                                "<td id='Señal'>" + item.Funciono + "</td>" +
                                "</tr>";
                            $('#Table').append(rows);
                        }); //End of foreach Loop
                        console.log(data);
                    }, //End of AJAX Success function

                    failure: function (data) {
                        alert(data.responseText);
                    }, //End of AJAX failure function
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert(data.responseText);
                    } //End of AJAX error function

                });
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

En la ventana que muestra de alert, el javascrip si están los datos devueltos por la consulta, pero luego me sale undefined.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qxp1P.png)

Comment: ¿Qué valores tiene `data`? Es posible que tengas que hacer un JSON.parse...

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado. Resulta que en JavaScript se distinguen las mayúsculas de las minúsculas. Luego los campos de la entidad señales están en la BD en mayúsculas, y yo en el código las ponía en minúsculas.

Gracias por todo.